# Rails action cables broadcast once and transmitting multiple times using async

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am developing a server validated hive board game with rails and having a issue with using action cables with async set for development. I see in the terminal the server broadcasts once and transmits the same message around 30 times. Is this normal behavior? Should I be using async for this sort of task? Also, is it possible to force rails to only transmit once? I have tried implementing a simple client side state system so the first transmission makes a change that the following transmission will see and do nothing but it appears as though sometimes another transmission is processed before the state is effected.

game_channel.rb

```
class GameChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "player_#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    Game.forfeit(current_user.id)
  end

  def take_turn(data)
    data["action"] = "take_turn"
    GameValidator.make_move(current_user.id, data)
  end
end
```

Game.coffee

```
//= require cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree .

this.App = {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
App.game = App.cable.subscriptions.create "GameChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    switch data.action
      when "game_start"
        start_game(data.msg)
      when "take_turn"
        if game.turn == data.color
          game.flop_turn()
          if data.move_type == "move"
            game.move_piece(data.q, data.r, data.to_q, data.to_r)
            draw_all_ctx();
          else
            game.place_piece(data.q, data.r, data.code, data.color);
            draw_all_ctx();

  send_turn: (move_type, code, q, r, to_q, to_r) ->
    data = {};
    data.color = game.color;
    data.move_type = move_type;
    data.code = code;
    data.q = q;
    data.r = r;
    data.to_r = to_r
    data.to_q = to_q
    @perform 'take_turn', data
```

game_validator.rb

```
class GameValidator

  def self.set_opponents(uid1, uid2)
    user1 = User.find(uid1)
    user2 = User.find(uid2)
    user1.update_attribute(:opponent_id, uid2)
    user2.update_attribute(:opponent_id, uid1)
  end

  def self.get_opponent(uid)
    user = User.find(uid)
    user.opponent_id
  end

  def self.start(uuid1, uuid2)
    white, black = [uuid1, uuid2].shuffle
    user = User.find(uuid1)
    game = Game.find(user.game_id)
    game.update_attribute(:white_id, white)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "player_#{white}", {action:     "game_start", msg: "white"}
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "player_#{black}", {action:     "game_start", msg: "black"}

    set_opponents(uuid1, uuid2)
  end

  def self.forfeit(uuid)
    if winner = get_opponent(uid)
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "player_#{winner}", {action:     "opponent_forfeits"}
    end
  end


  def self.make_move(uuid, data)
    opponent = get_opponent(uuid)
    game = Game.find(User.find(uuid).game_id)
    #if valid move
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "player_#{uuid}", data
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "player_#{opponent}", data
  end     
end
```

Here is what the terminal looks like

> [ActionCable] Broadcasting to player_206: {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} [ActionCable] Broadcasting to player_101:
>   {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3,
>   "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} GameChannel transmitting
>   {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3,
>   "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from
>   player_206) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_206) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101) GameChannel
>   transmitting {"color"=>"black", "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1,
>   "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6, "action"=>"take_turn"} (via
>   streamed from player_101) GameChannel transmitting {"color"=>"black",
>   "move_type"=>"move", "code"=>-1, "q"=>5, "r"=>3, "to_r"=>3, "to_q"=>6,
>   "action"=>"take_turn"} (via streamed from player_101)

Comment: Please spend a bit more time in making your answer better to read and add some code examples. That will help you have more changes getting an answer.